# Less Compiler (lessc) exits without message, with status code 1

Tags: less, npm, ubuntu-14.04

I installed less on my Ubuntu machine recently, using:

```
sudo npm install -g less
```

Now when I try the following:

```
lessc less/main.less
```

I expect the ouput CSS. Instead, I get blank.

Output status code is 1 (error).

```
user@comp:/path/to/parent/dir$ echo $?
1

user@comp:/path/to/parent/dir$ lessc less/main.less && echo "Success" || echo "Error"
Error
```

But I can't see an error.

What's weirder is,

```
user@comp:/path/to/parent/dir$ lessc --version && echo "Success" || echo "Error"
Error
```

I can't do ANYTHING with it.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, nothing.

Comment: Most likely you need to use `sudo` for the global `npm` installations. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8872851/2712740 for example.

Comment: sorry, my bad, I did use sudo just didn't point out in the question

Comment: Ah, OK. So it looks like you also need to add `node/bin` path to the `$PATH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, I'm not sure why, but the script env for lessc was set improperly.

I found the solution online somewhere in a tutorial of how to install LESS on Ubuntu, I'm not sure where that was.

Anyways... If you open lessc:

```
user@comp:~$ gksudo gedit /usr/local/bin/lessc
```

You'll see this first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

Which you need to set to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nodejs
```

(add `js` at the end)

And voila! It works flawlessly.

Comment: Hmm, it's interesting. Strictly speaking `node` is correct there and `nodejs` is not. Most likely it's the `apt-get install nodejs` that creates not so proper `nodejs` link to the `node` executable.

Comment: Yeah feels like it. I've installed `node` before but that didn't help it at all. I'm not sure what to do. Would symlinking `node` to `nodejs` work?

Comment: Or maybe just renaming `usr/bin/nodejs` (or its copy) to `node`. Either of this should do the trick I guess. Btw.: http://askubuntu.com/questions/235655/node-js-conflicts-sbin-node-vs-usr-bin-node